# Css for navigation arrows to persist vertically on both left and right sides of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A bit weak on the CSS front. I am trying to achieve the exact efferct as on http://www.usatoday.com/. The left and right navigation arrows persist vertically even if you scroll up and down the page vertically. Does anyone have any sample code to do that?[image: Arrows on both outer left and outer right]

Comment: Yes, usatoday.com does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll wanted to give them `position: fixed`. If you'd like them to be centered vertically you could do something like this*:

```
.nav-arrow {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

See this [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/2b94b97aa38713c00b1a2c89883b71e0)

*you'll need to be sure to give them a specified height

Comment: Thanks. Worked... Made a slight adjustment. Added top: 50%; to move it to the middle vertically and right:0; for the right arrow to snap right.

Comment: @DeAn which version of firefox are you in? This demo http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/full/2b94b97aa38713c00b1a2c89883b71e0/ seems to be working for me in firefox 28.0 osx 10.9.